# Update / create subdocument in array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

I got a data like this in my User collection on my MongoDB database

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5890a9598c36d45435d521c7"),
    "name" : "Test Testsson",
    "email": "test@test.com,"
    "tasks": [{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5890a9598c36d45435d521ce"),
            "sessionid" : 0,
            "value" : 7,
            "actions" : [ 
                {
                    "taskid" : 17,
                    "time" : 0.85302734375,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5890a9598c36d45435d521d6")
                }, 
                {
                    "taskid" : 5,
                    "time" : 1.39321899414063,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5890a9598c36d45435d521d5")
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5890a9598c36d45435d521qw"),
            "sessionid" : 1,
            "value" : 7,
            "actions" : [ 
                {
                    "taskid" : 1,
                    "time" : 0.85302734375,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5890a9598c36d45435d521zx")
                }, 
                {
                    "taskid" : 5,
                    "time" : 1.39321899414063,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5890a9598c36d45435d521yt")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I post data to my node / mongoose application and I want to update the tasks array.

I do a POST to /api/user/task/5890a9598c36d45435d521c7
with Body:

```
{
    "sessionid" : 2,
    "value" : 12,
    "actions" : [ 
        {
            "taskid" : 4,
            "time" : 0.85302734375,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5890a9598c36d45435d521zx")
        }, 
        {
            "taskid" : 9,
            "time" : 1.39321899414063,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5890a9598c36d45435d521yt")
        }
    ]
}
```

I can find my tasks with this query:

```
User.findOne({
    _id: ObjectId('58909be40c50e2d0345e916e'),
    "tasks.sessionid": 0},
    function(...){/* blah blah */});
```

But how do I update the data in the tasks array?

- If the sessionid exists I want to update the subdocument with the
  request body (given that the User exists)
- If the sessionid DONT exist I want to create a new object from the
  request body in the tasks array (given that the User exists)
- If the ObjectId of the User in the url parameter DONT exist send http
  status: 500

I tried with update and findAndModify but cant get it to work as expected. Anyone got any idees how to do this.

Comment: Can you show your attempts with `update` and `findAndModify`?

Comment: From robomongo: db.getCollection('users').findOneAndUpdate({_id: ObjectId('5890a9598c36d45435d521c7'),
    "tasks.sessionid": 0}, {
     $addToSet: <BODY>
    }, {upsert: true}) . That creates new dokuments in the tasks array. Even if the sessionid exists

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to supplement additional info in the question, not comments.